# How to link two cells in google spreadsheet and is it possible?

Tags: google-sheets

In google spreadsheet How to link two cells?

For example,  `If I click a1 it has to highlight the c1 cell`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible.

It is similar to linking another spreadsheet using `HYPERLINK()`.

Click on the cell you want to link from > Insert > Link (or cmd/ctrl + k) > "Select a range of cells to link" > Enter cell number > OK > Apply

[image]

This will link to a cell in the same sheet.

**You can also link to a cell in a different sheet**

Goto the cell you want to link to > right click > select "Get link to this cell" (this will copy the cell link to your clipboard) > Insert new link and hit paste > Apply

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

At this time, it's not possible. The alternatives are to use an add-on or to use Google Apps Script.

## See also

- [Use Add-ons & Apps-Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)